# Move current file to another folder based on drop list selected

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried to search for an answer, and have tried various VBA available. Unfortunately none seemed to work.

What I am hoping to achieve is:

1. Move (not copy) the current Excel workbook (this is the file I have opened and where the drop list is located) from its current folder to another folder
2. The workbook will not change name
3. Achieve this by using a drop list

For example: source folder = c:\test, destination folder = c:\dest\ and c:\other. If I select "dest" in the drop list, the file will move from c:\test\ to c:\dest. If I select "Other", it will move to c:\other\ (all folders will be pre-created)

Below is what I have so far, but it does not appear to work:

```
If Target.Column = 5 And Target.Row = 8 Then

    If Target.Value = "Dest" Then
        Dim sFileNameExt As String
        Dim sFilePath As String
        Dim sNewPath As String

        sNewPath = "c:\Dest\"
        sFilePath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
        sFileNameExt = ActiveWorkbook.Name
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs sNewPath & sFileNameExt
        Kill sFilePath & "\" & sFileNameExt
    ElseIf Target.Value = "Other" Then
        sNewPath = "c:\Other\"
        sFilePath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
        sFileNameExt = ActiveWorkbook.Name
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs sNewPath & sFileNameExt
        Kill sFilePath & "\" & sFileNameExt
    End If
End If
```

Any help will be very much appreciated (oh if it is not obvious, I am extremely new to VBA...)

Comment: You can't move the file while you have it open. A workaround is create an app that you Shell open with the source/dest paths, close Excel, wait 5 seconds and then move the file and then open it again. Not pretty or a great UX.

Answer (score 1):

### Move `ThisWorkbook`

- The code needs to be copied to the sheet module (e.g. `Sheet1`) of the worksheet containing the dropdowns.

**Basic**

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const sAddress As String = "E8"
    Const dInitialPath As String = "C:\"
    
    Dim sCell As Range: Set sCell = Intersect(Me.Range(sAddress), Target)
    If sCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = Me.Parent
    
    Dim dSubFolderName As String: dSubFolderName = CStr(sCell.Value)
    
    Select Case dSubFolderName
    Case "Dest", "Other"
        Dim sFilePath As String: sFilePath = swb.FullName
        Dim dFilePath As String
        dFilePath = dInitialPath & dSubFolderName & "\" & swb.Name
        If StrComp(sFilePath, dFilePath, vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite without confirmation
                swb.SaveAs dFilePath
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            Kill sFilePath
            MsgBox "The new filepath is '" & dFilePath & "'.", _
                vbInformation
        Else
            MsgBox "You are trying to move this file to the same location.", _
                vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End Select
    
End Sub
```

**Improved**

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    MoveThisWorkbook Target
End Sub

Sub MoveThisWorkbook(ByVal Target As Range)
    Const ProcName As String = "MoveThisWorkbook"
    
    ' Define constants.
    ' Source
    Const sAddress As String = "E8"
    ' Destination
    Const dInitialPath As String = "C:\"
    Const dSubFoldersList As String = "Dest,Other"
    ' If you modify one of the following two (e.g. '".xlsb"'),
    ' you need to modify the other accordingly (e.g. 'xlExcel12').
    Const dNotSavedFileExtension As String = ".xlsm"
    Const dNotSavedFileFormat As Long = xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
    ' Booleans
    Const InformWhenMoved As Boolean = True
    Const ExploreNewLocation As Boolean = True
    
    ' Reference the source worksheet ('sws').
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = Target.Worksheet
    
    ' Reference the source (dropdown) cell ('sCell').
    Dim sCell As Range: Set sCell = Intersect(sws.Range(sAddress), Target)
    If sCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Return the subfolders from the list ('dSubFoldersList')
    ' in the destination subfolders array ('dSubFolders').
    Dim dSubFolders() As String: dSubFolders = Split(dSubFoldersList, ",")
    
    ' Write the dropdown subfolder, the string representation of the value
    ' in the source cell, to a variable ('dSubFolder').
    Dim dSubFolder As String: dSubFolder = CStr(sCell.Value)
    
    ' Check if the dropdown subfolder is not contained
    ' in the destination subfolders array.
    If IsError(Application.Match(dSubFolder, dSubFolders, 0)) Then
        MsgBox "'" & dSubFolder & "' is not contained in the following list:" _
            & vbLf & Join(dSubFolders, vbLf), vbExclamation, ProcName
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Write the (application) path separator to a variable ('APS').
    Dim APS As String: APS = Application.PathSeparator
    
    ' Append a path separator to the initial destination
    ' folder path, if it doesn't end with one already.
    Dim diPath As String: diPath = dInitialPath
    If StrComp(Right(diPath, Len(APS)), APS, vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
        diPath = diPath & APS
    End If
    
    ' Validate the initial destination folder path.
    If Len(Dir(diPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The initial destination folder location '" & diPath _
            & "' doesn't exist.", vbCritical, ProcName
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Build the destination folder path ('dFolderPath') by appending
    ' the subfolder and a path separator to the initial destination
    ' folder path.
    Dim dFolderPath As String: dFolderPath = diPath & dSubFolder & APS
    
    ' Validate the destination folder path i.e. create it
    ' if it doesn't exist.
    If Len(Dir(dFolderPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir dFolderPath
        
    ' Reference the source workbook ('swb').
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = sws.Parent
    
    ' Write the destination file path to a variable ('dPath').
    Dim dPath As String: dPath = dFolderPath & swb.Name
    
    ' Move (or save) the file.
    If Len(swb.Path) > 0 Then ' the file has previously been saved
        ' Write the source file path to a variable ('sPath').
        Dim sPath As String: sPath = swb.FullName
        ' Validate the destination file path
        ' i.e. check if the source and destination file paths are equal.
        ' Note that the comparison is case-insensitive due to 'vbTextCompare'.
        If StrComp(sPath, dPath, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "You are trying to move this file to its current " _
                & "location ('" & sPath & "').", vbExclamation, ProcName
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite (without confirmation)
            swb.SaveAs dPath ' save as new
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Kill sPath ' delete old
    Else ' the file has previously not been saved
        dPath = dPath & dNotSavedFileExtension ' apppend the file extension
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite (without confirmation)
            swb.SaveAs dPath, dNotSavedFileFormat ' use 'FileFormat'
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
            
    ' Inform showing the destination file path.
    If InformWhenMoved Then
        MsgBox "The new file location is '" & dPath & "'.", _
            vbInformation, ProcName
    End If
    
    ' Explore the destination file path's folder.
    If ExploreNewLocation Then swb.FollowHyperlink swb.Path

End Sub
```